# Why do I get an unexpected character error when loading .json files in R

Tags: r, json

I am trying to load a local json file in R. I am using a package called Sofia that includes the json library. I also tried other packages like rjson and the RJSONIO packages but I get the same error (`error in ProcessFiles(File=File), unexpected character E.`

This is example code when I use the a local package Sofia:

```
data<-ProcessFiles(file="data1.json",method="Sofia.method")
```

When I apply the same package to some old .json files it works normally without error.
I tried to change the encoding of the file to UTF-8 but the error persists. The file encoding is ANSI
Can anybody help with this?

Comment: Could you post the JSON?

Comment: Without an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) it's hard to do more than guess, but have you run the file through a linter?